# Batch Delete IAM Roles from CLI Script

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli

I'm working on cleaning up an AWS account with hundreds of unused IAM roles.  Rather than delete them by selecting a few at a time from the console, I'd like to delete all that fit the criteria of their **last activity** being greater than 60 days ago.  An example role with the `list-roles` AWS IAM CLI command returns the following JSON:

```
 {
        "Path": "/service-role/",
        "RoleName": "ExampleRoleName",
        "RoleId": "ExampleRoleID",
        "Arn": "ExampleRoleARN",
        "CreateDate": "ExampleRoleDate",
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": [
                {
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Principal": {
                        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
                    },
                    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
                }
            ]
        },
        "MaxSessionDuration": 3600
    }
```

Is there a way to gather data on their last activity and use that in a script to delete roles with no activity in the last 180 days?  Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Last activity is available from the [get-role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/get-role.html) command. So you could use `list-roles` with a query to extract the role names, then iterate over that.

Comment: But the reason I haven't turned this into an answer is that it's not a great approach. Do you know any programming languages other than `bash`?

Comment: @Parsifal - Python would be another viable approach as well!  I've updated the question to serve a broader audience and allow you to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the basic loop in Python (IAM also supports the "resource" API, which is somewhat simpler, but this is a copy-paste-edit from code I already had):

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('iam')

paginator = client.get_paginator('list_roles')
for page in paginator.paginate():
    for listed_role in page['Roles']:
        role_name = listed_role['RoleName']
        role = client.get_role(RoleName=role_name)['Role']
        last_used = role.get('RoleLastUsed', {}).get('LastUsedDate')
        print(f"{role_name}: {last_used}")
```

Note: when deleting a role, you first have to detach all managed policies from the role, using `client.detach_role_policy()`.

Answer (score 0):

Bash only alternative:

```
aws iam list-roles --query 'Roles[*].[RoleName]' --output text \
| xargs -I % \
aws iam get-role --role-name %  --output text \
--query 'Role.[RoleName,CreateDate, RoleLastUsed.LastUsedDate]'
```